# Facebook graph api with app token for 60 days

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an access token and the following url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/414950271951116?fields=posts.limit(50).until(1451606399).since(1420070400)%7Bmessage%2Ccreated_time%7D&access_token= INSERT APP TOKEN
```

Originally I made an app token which could make requests for 60 days. It seems that it's not working now. Is anyone else having this issue or am I doing something wrong? I don't seem to get any error messages.

Comment: Is that a user profile or a page that you want to read data from? If user, what permissions did the user grant your app? If it is a page, is it public, and not restricted in any way (by age, location, for alcohol-related content)? And what does _“It seems that it's not working now”_ actually mean – error messages, …?

Comment: app tokens are valid forever. make sure you understand the difference between the tokens: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: also, "not working" is not a sufficient error/problem description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was my mistake. It seems that this particular user has blocked people from using the API on their Facebook page.